# How do you idiomatically implement a nontrivial typestate pattern in Rust?

Tags: rust, design-patterns

I'm trying to build the FSM of a simple CPU, which consists of about 40 states, with loops, and many conditionals across many variables of the overall CPU state. This FSM operates like a simple Turing Machine; reading memory cells (think vector of u16), computing some results, and storing them back into memory.

My question is: how is this implemented idiomatically in Rust?

The way I've considered it, you would do something like this:

1. Have a base enum representing the states.
2. Have another enum for each state which represents transitions (but maybe all in the same enum?).
3. Somehow you'd have to access the *CPU state* (value of all the different registers etc) to know how to emit the next state transition, but to be efficient about it, you'd need to be able to pass different subsets of the CPU state, yet somehow only mutate a single copy that represents the CPU state after the computation.
4. You could probably build a vector of "state diffs" which you could apply all at once when you reach certain states, which would also be good for implementing a simple debugger.

I'm new to rust, so modelling these sort of complex compositional type problems still doesn't come very naturally.

If you want to see how things work so far, I have a repo here: https://github.com/ijustlovemath/lrc3

Comment: Surely there's a Rust coded CPU emulator of some sort you can use as a reference here.

Comment: Due to that, you'll often find the design of Rust code steers towards different patterns than you might be used to with a *promiscuously mutable* language like C or C++. For example, you might "wall off" your CPU in an a thread that maintains a mutable reference to the CPU state, but which can, through debugger checkpoints or otherwise, kick out copies of the state to any who ask through a simple message bus mechanism. Those copies can be mutated at-will in their local context without interfering with the main CPU instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to make a `Cpu<State>`, then make one struct per state that carries all the state-specific data, and write an `impl` per state that provides methods that transition to the next state.

```
struct Cpu<State> {
    data: Vec<u16>,
    state: State,
}


struct State1 {
    foo: String
}

struct State2 {
    bar: usize
}

impl Cpu<State1> {
    fn transition(self) -> Cpu<State2> {
        let Self { data, state: State1 { foo } }  = self;
        let bar = foo.len();
        Cpu { data, state: State2 { bar } }
    }
}
```

You will essentially have encoded your enum variants in the type system. Valid transitions between states are exposed as methods, and invalid ones can't be represented.

Comment: You can't do *runtime* conditions with typestate, because Rust *eliminates* types during compilation.

Comment: @ijustlovemath I believe serde uses typestate as described in the answer. E.g. `serialize_map()` returns a `SerializeMap`, which provides `serialize_key()` and `serialize_value()` ops, and an `end()` transition. OTOH, `serialize_struct()` returns a `SerializeStruct` with just `serialize_field()` and `end()`. When you define a serializer for your type, the code performs a sequence of these operations known at compile time. It cannot change its mind in the middle - e.g. it cannot start serializing a struct, and then proceed as if it were a map. If that were supported, typestate couldn't be used.

Comment: So it might be that typestate is *not* a good fit for what you're doing. It would be a good fit if you were writing *Rust* programs for your virtual CPU, not for interpreting machine code. But please take this with a grain of salt - I'm not a typing expert, and it could well be that I'm misunderstanding how typestate is applied to various domains.